# How can you execute a string which checks for mutual values across multiple lists

Tags: python-3.7

When I execute the code attached, everything works fine except for the "return(exec(string))" part. I can't get it to return the mutual value of {1} I'm looking for.

I've tried doing "return(eval(string))" instead and that didn't work either.

```
def match(listoflists):
    string = ""

    if len(listoflists) > 1:
        i = 0

        while i < len(listoflists):
            string = string + " & set(listoflists[" + str(i) + "])"

            i += 1

    string = string[3:]
    return(exec(string))

match([[1, 2, 3], [1, 7, 8], [1, 4, 5], [1, 6, 9]])
```

The expected result is {1}. The actual result is that nothing is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I made the question, but I found the solution and just wanted to share it as to not waste anyone's time. All I did was change the lines:

```
string = string[3:]
return(exec(string))
```

to:

```
string = "print(" + string[3:] + ")"
return(exec(string))
```

and that worked a treat, returning the expected value of {1}